# Xcode GDB Cannot Connect to Device. Really annoying and fidgety

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, gdb

Background: As I'm developing an app that needs to be run on a device, I often get weird errors with Xcode. They are really annoying and to get the builds to run on the device , its almost like I have to do an offering to Xcode to get it to work. Normally, I would just reboot the device, reboot the mac, clean all targets, disconnect device, reposition USB cable, and turn the device off. But the development device I'm using has a broken sleep button. I can't turn it off.

What do I do?

Here are the errors I've faced

Broken Pipes

```
The Service is Invalid Please check your setup and try again.
 (0xE8000022).
```

and the most annoying one, after the Build Works, I get this in the console and no other message. The first line is fine, but then the next line seems to be the issue.

```
    This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
target remote-mobile (null)
warning: Couldn't connect to unix service: "(null)", error: "No such file or directory".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings>General>Reset and then choose one (network settings apparently causes a reboot, but content and settings definitely will if you don't mind) will allow you to reboot the device. You can also wait for the battery to run down, restore via iTunes or jailbreak and run `reboot`, but you obviously shouldn't test on a jailbroken device.

Comment: Just tired Reset Network and the device rebooted. This should solve some issues! Thanks!

Comment: and this also solved my xcode issues, if anyone has similar errors, restart!

Comment: No problem - I had a problem where my app was installed but never run - I forgot to try restarting!